# How to get final result from asynchronous callback in Retrofit?

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit

I use Retrofit 2 to implementation REST in my app. One of my callbacks is asynchronous. I need to get data from `onResponse()` method to pass on but this method is executed at the end (after return result, when a thread did other things). There is part of my code where you can find my async callback:

```
 public class JSONManager {

     //...

     public Result insertUser(final Context context, final String login, final String password, final String salt, final String email) {
            IUserApi userAPI = retrofit.create(IUserApi.class);

            Call<User> user = userAPI.insertUser(login, password, salt, email);
            user.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                    try {
                         if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            int mysqlId = response.body().mysqlId;
                            int temp = response.code();
                            if (mysqlId > 0) {
                                result.setResponseCode(1);
                                if (sqLiteManager.addUser(login, password, salt, email, mysqlId)) {
                                    result.setResponseCode(4);
                                    result.setResult(true);
                                } else {
                                    result.setResponseCode(5);
                                    result.setResult(false);
                                }
                            } else {
                                result.setResponseCode(2);
                                result.setResult(false);
                            }
                        } else {
                            result.setResponseCode(3);
                            result.setResult(false);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        result.setResult(false);
                        result.setResponseCode(3);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                    result.setResponseCode(2);
                    result.setResult(false);
                }
            });

        return result;
    }

    //...
 }
```

Here I try get the result, but unfortunately I don't receive expected result because, how I wrote before, the `user.enqueue()` method is executed after executing `onClickRegistrationButton()` method (so, too late).

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //...   

    private void onClickRegistrationButton() {

            //...

            JSONManager jsonManager = new JSONManager();
            Result result = jsonManager.insertUser(getApplicationContext(), login, encryptedPassword, salt, email);

            //...
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: What is `result`? Where do you declare that variable?

Comment: I forgot about it. It's an object of my own type.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to return a Result object in your `insertUser` method, you can try calling a function passing that Result as a parameter on both `onResponse` and `onFailure`:

```
callNewFunction(Result result);
```

---

Something like:

```
public class JSONManager {

    //...

    public void insertUser(final Context context, final String login, final String password, final String salt, final String email) {
        IUserApi userAPI = retrofit.create(IUserApi.class);

        Call<User> user = userAPI.insertUser(login, password, salt, email);
        user.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                try {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        int mysqlId = response.body().mysqlId;
                        int temp = response.code();
                        if (mysqlId > 0) {
                            result.setResponseCode(1);
                            if (sqLiteManager.addUser(login, password, salt, email, mysqlId)) {
                                result.setResponseCode(4);
                                result.setResult(true);
                            } else {
                                result.setResponseCode(5);
                                result.setResult(false);
                            }
                        } else {
                            result.setResponseCode(2);
                            result.setResult(false);
                        }
                    } else {
                        result.setResponseCode(3);
                        result.setResult(false);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    result.setResult(false);
                    result.setResponseCode(3);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                callNewFunction(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                result.setResponseCode(2);
                result.setResult(false);

                callNewFunction(result);
            }
        });
    }

    private void callNewFunction(Result result){
        Log.d(TAG, "callNewFunction: " + result);
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I did something like this but it is called when `user.enqueue()` is executed, so it return a default `result` value, not a value which I expect, and it call your method after that.